# static string vs string in Java

Tags: java, string

This one is a bit of conceptual question. I know strings are constant; their values cannot be changed after they are created. Consider this declaration -

```
private final static String ABC = "abc";
```

vs

```
private final String ABC = "abc";
```

Why is the first one better in terms of performance?

Is there any reason why the second one would be needed if the value of ABC not being updated in the class anywhere as such directly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you understand the difference between `static` and non-`static`?

Comment: Strings are _immutable_, but not necessarily _constant_.

Comment: @oliver Charlesworth - yes, I understand the difference between static and non-static. The question was specific to STRINGS. Thanks to all who marked the question as duplicate BUT the link provided as a duplicate doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard - Please refer to this link - "Strings are constant; their values cannot be changed after they are created. String buffers support mutable strings. Because String objects are immutable they can be shared. For example:" http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html
It is important not to treat String in java like any other data type. That is something most developers dont pay heed to. I was trying to get my basics correct with the question.

Answer (score 2):

The first one creates only one copy for all the instances of your class.But the second one creates ABC for each instances.

The first one can be called without the object itself.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is ~better~  because you won't have an extra `String` reference in all your instances. Because they are both constant expressions, you'll get the same behavior in the class byte code (where their value is used).

<sub>There are also a few differences to consider if you use reflection anywhere.</sub>